# How to use Labstack Echo ReverseProxy ModifyResponse using streams

Tags: http, go, go-echo

Labstack Echo v4 has recently been updated to include [ModifyResponse](https://github.com/labstack/echo/blob/master/middleware/proxy.go) hook (ala golang's httputil [ReverseProxy](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy)).

Most of the examples of using this seem to leverage ioutil.ReadAll().

For example:

```
func UpdateResponse(r *http.Response) error {
    b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    buf := bytes.NewBufferString("Monkey")
    buf.Write(b)
    r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(buf)
    r.Header["Content-Length"] = []string{fmt.Sprint(buf.Len())}
    return nil
}
```

What I am looking to do is to avoid waiting for the entire response (from ReadAll) and monitor the stream for certain content (i.e. `class='blue'`) then replace it with different text (i.e. `class='blue-green'`)

How can this be done using streams efficiently and with as little allocations as possible?

Comment: Try reading it to some buffer, replace string in the buffer, and then return https://golang.org/pkg/io/#MultiReader

Comment: It is already a reader, so I hoping to not have to buffer it; as that is still creating a copy of the data.   Pipe seems to get close, but there were some issues I ran into dealing with HTML/JSON structures.   I guess it would have to run through a stream parser.